# Using Pagination on product view using Category ID

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I feel I have asked alot of questions recently and Im sorry if this is relatively simple but I am struggling to get this working correctly.

I want to add pagination to my product view but when I add the pagination numbers code as seen at the bottom of the page they do not show.

I'm also aware that I should be using mysqli but I want to get this working first before moving over.

Thanks.

**Show Product**

```
   <div class="link" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color: white">
<?php
include("../script/dbconnect.php");
include("../script/get_product.php");

$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']); 

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    if ( ! category_exists('name', $post['name']) ) {
        $post['name'] = 'Uncategorised';
    }
    ?>  
    <ul class='featured'>

            <li class='headhighlight'><?php echo $post['title']; ?></li>  
            <li class='pricehigh'><?php echo $post['price']; ?></li>
            <li class='imagefeat'><img class='imagelink' src='<?php echo $post['picture']; ?>' alt='$name'></li>                
            </ul>   

<?php
    }
?>


    </div>
```

**get_product.php**

```
    <?php
    function get_posts($id = null, $cat_id = null) {
    $posts = array();

//Pagination Code
    $perpage = 10;
     if(isset($_GET["page_num"]))
     {
      $page_num = intval($_GET["page_num"]);
     }
     else
     {
      $page_num = 1;
     }
     if ($page_num < 1)
     {
       $page_num = 1;
     }
     $calc = $perpage * $page_num;
     $start = $calc - $perpage;

//End pagination code

        $query ="SELECT  `products`.`id` AS  `name` ,  `products_cat`.`id` AS  `category_id` , `products`.`name` AS `title` ,  `description` ,  `price` ,  `sale` ,  `picture` 
    FROM  `products` 
    INNER JOIN  `products_cat` ON  `products`.`prod_id` =  `products_cat`.`id` ";

        if ( isset($id) ) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $query .= " WHERE `products`.`id` = {$id}";
        }

        if ( isset($cat_id) ) {
            $cat_id = (int) $cat_id;
            $query .= " WHERE `products_cat`.`id` = {$cat_id}";
    }

        $query .= " ORDER BY `products`.`price` DESC Limit $start, $perpage";

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        echo mysql_error();
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
            $posts[] = $row;
            }

        return $posts;
    }
```

**Pagination Code - to add page numbers - would be placed in showproduct.php**

```
<p class="pagination">
<?php
    if(isset($page_num))
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) As Total FROM products");
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows)
        {
            $rs = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $total = $rs["Total"];
        }
        $totalPages = ceil($total / $perpage);
        if($page_num <=1 )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;"> < </span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page_num - 1;
            echo '<span><a id="page_a_link" href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page_num=' . $j . '"> < </a></span>';
        }
        for($i=1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
        {
            if($i<>$page_num)
            {
                echo '<span><a href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page_num=' .$i. '" id="page_a_link">' . $i . '</a></span>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">' . $i . '</span>';
            }
        }
        if($page_num == $totalPages )
        {
            echo '<span id="page_links" style="font-weight:bold;">Next ></span>';
        }
        else
        {
            $j = $page_num + 1;
            echo '<span><a href="../admin/admin.master.php?page=list_products.php&page_num=' .$j. '" id="page_a_link"> > </a></span>';
        }
    }
?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query($posts);
```

In the `get_posts` function you declare this variable as an array, fill it from a query result and then you return it... so it will never work. What were you trying to do here? You have to pass a string to the mysql_query function with correct MySQL query structure.

EDIT: adding the part of the code that is giving problems, and a possible fix.

```
$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']);

  $i = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post){
   ....
```

does it work this way? You already did the query with the LIMIT inside the get_posts function and returned the data.

Comment: I may of removed part of my code here when I was adding the pagiantion. How would i go about fixing this. Thanks Naryl.

Comment: hmm it's a bit hard to tell. Let's see if I understand what you are trying to do: you pass a page number to the script then inside the get_posts function you are doing the pagination and returning a array `$posts` with the results, why are you doing a query again? shouldn't you just display the results?

Comment: Hi naryl. I edited my code above with a foreach function. It works paginating the results but when I add the pagination numbers (as seen on the bottom of the edited page) they do not show. So the pagination works but the numbers of the pages arn't appearing. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I presume Ill need to redefine the $page_num variable somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']);
```

returns array, of something. After it you trying to make mysql_query(array); Try to make

```
var_dump($posts); and copy print here. Or try next: 
$posts = get_posts(null, $_GET['id']);
foreach($posts as $post){
$result[] = mysql_query($posts);
}
```

Comment: the posts variable is a array of $row of another query, so nope it won't work like this. I guess he wanted to construct new queries with the variable's contents and forgot to do this step.